# I am getting None as output, but I want output as 10, 20 30?

Tags: django

```
    <select name="dropdown" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
      <option value= 1 >10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    
    def dropdown(request):      
        print(request.POST.get('dropdown'))
        return render(request, 'ndtgui/dropdown.html')
```

The above one is my html file and below is view in django.

> Blockquote

Comment: You need a `<form>`, not just a `<select>`.

Comment: Also <option value= 1 >10</option> , here is a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are missing:

**html-file (let's call it *index.html*):**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="dropdown" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="get select data">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.POST.get('dropdown')
        print(result)
    return render(request, '.../index.html')
```